# API controller implements 2 POST methods with different URI, Call to one POST is not routed correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-apicontroller

I implemented below 3 methods in my apicontroller->

EnableFlowAnalytics:

Action= POST, MethodURI= api/ConfigurationApiController/EnableFlowAnalytics, route map= config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( "EnableFlowAnalytics Route", "api/ConfigurationApiController/EnableFlowAnalytics", new { controller = "ConfigurationApi" });

DeleteFlowAnalytics:

Action= POST, MethodURI= api/ConfigurationApiController/DeleteFlowAnalytics, route map= config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( "DeleteFlowAnalytics Route", "api/ConfigurationApiController/DeleteFlowAnalytics", new { controller = "ConfigurationApi" });

GetFlowAnalytics:

Action= GET, MethodURI= api/ConfigurationApiController/GetFlowAnalyticsConfig/subscriptions/ {subscriptionGuid}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/networkSecurityGroups/{nsgName},
route map= config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( "GetFlowAnalyticsConfig Route", "api/ConfigurationApiController/GetFlowAnalyticsConfig/subscriptions/{subscriptionGuid}/resourceGroups /{resourceGroupName}/networkSecurityGroups/{nsgName}", new { controller = "ConfigurationApi" });

When I call these three methods from my client code, EnableFlowAnalytics and GetFlowAnalyticsConfig are getting routed correctly but DeleteFlowAnalytics is not getting routed , instead of delete the call is going to EnableFlowAnalytics again. I am unable to understand this routing logic as the URI is not ambiguous ,it’s totally different.

```
public class ConfigurationApiController : ApiController
{
   [System.Web.Http.Route("api/ConfigurationApiController/DeleteFlowAnalytics")]
[System.Web.Http.ActionName("DeleteFlowAnalytics")]
public void DeleteFlowAnalytics(
    string nsgResourceId)
{
     //implementation}

[System.Web.Http.Route("api/ConfigurationApiController/EnableFlowAnalytics")]
[System.Web.Http.ActionName("EnableFlowAnalytics")]
public void EnableFlowAnalytics(
EnableFlowAnalyticsArgs enableFlowAnalytics)
{
     //implemetation
 }
```

Comment: Is the `string nsgResourceId` in the POST body or do you want to target the resource as such: `[System.Web.Http.Route("api/ConfigurationApiController/DeleteFlowAnalytics/{nsgResourceId}")]`?

Comment: Why are you specifying both the routing methods? Do not change the conventional method (MapHttpRoute). I mean try removing the conventional route.

Comment: Do not include controller word in the url

Comment: Please edit the question and include code in the proper format. There is an option to insert code in the StackOverflow editor.